# Benefactor badge not awarded?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges

I added a bounty to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27771764/curses-array-browsing-with-keyboard-in-ruby), then when I got the perfect answer I up-voted it and marked as accepted.

Is there any reason I didn't get the benefactor badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The description of the [Benefactor badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/221/benefactor) reads:

> First bounty you **manually** awarded on your own question.

Emphasis is mine, on the word "manually" - you must click the "+50" icon and confirm in order to award the bounty manually and get the badge.

The bounty might still get awarded even if you don't do it manually, but you won't get the badge in this case.

Comment: Damn, I thought you just had to accept the answer! Oh well :)

Comment: @Peter yeah, next time! :)

Answer (score 2):

You did not award the bounty, so you will not get the badge.

To get the benefactor badge you need to award the bounty yourself, instead of letting it expire and be automatically awarded.

Comment: Nope, he  won't get it. This was done over a month ago, and I doubt it takes the job that long to run. He did not give it manually, that's why he didn't get the badge.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - you are right. I misread the post timeline.